# IP (not PORT!) forwarding inside Docker container

Tags: docker, networking

We have several containers which are connected to the same custom network with ipv6 support. Now we need one of those containers to act as the default gateway (in short, the default gateway of our custom network should be set to the ip of this one container).

This is rather impossible (or at least we did not find an answer to that). There is another option however.

Since we need to forward a specific ip address to another one we can simply use:

ip -6 route add xxxx:yy:: via aaaa:bb::c

in each container. That would be a rather unelegant but satisfaying solution. It does not work like that. I suppose we would need to restart the container network. I could not find a way to do this without restarting the container which would of course nullifies the above command.

Any idea on how to do this properly? I apologise for my possible direct tone in this message, I haven't slept much in the last few days and I am thinking of changing careers. How does rocket scientist sound? gotta be easier that working with docker...

Comment: `I could not find a way to do this without restarting the container which would, of course, nullifies the above command.` Is this the only problem with restarting the container? Or so you have other constraints for which you do not want to restart the container?

Comment: Q: why can't you just configure the network's DHCP to send your desired IP as the gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, no network restart was necessary. I had an error in the command syntax. Since I wanted to redirect *all* IPs to that specific one I had to write it like that:

```
ip -6 route add xxxx:yy::/64 via aaaa:bb::c
```

You can easily put this in a bash script and execute it every time a container starts:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install iproute2 -y
ip -6 route add xxxx:yy::/64 via aaaa:bb::c
```

Quick side note, for the IP command to be able to run the container has to run in "privileged" mode.

Comment: to minimize exposure, you can start it with the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability instead of using privileged mode, which adds a lot (all?) of capabilities to the container, most of which you don't need.